# Python getting User input with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In my Python program somehwere in between i pop-up a Tkinter GUI to get user Input. User selects option from a Tkinter.ttk Combobox. From here once the user closes the Tkinter window i want the selection made by user to be used further in the code. But upon close unable to get the user selection back into the code.

Please help.

Comment: You will need to get and save the input prior to closing the popup.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a `StringVar()` in the root window and then associate it with the `Combobox()` in the `Toplevel()` window. The combobox will change the value of the `StringVar()` and you can read it affter popup window is closed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

combotext = StringVar()

def get_input():
    popup = Toplevel()
    box = ttk.Combobox(popup, textvariable=combotext, state='readonly')
    box['values'] = ("Camembert", "Brie", "Tilsit", "Stilton")
    combotext.set('Choose')
    box.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

Button(root, text='Get input', command=get_input).pack(padx=90, pady=10)
Label(root, textvariable=combotext).pack(pady=(0,10))

root.mainloop()
```